# Mongoid Scopes: gain access to limit and skip within scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, mongoid

My problem is basically this:

I want to add a named scope with parameter `search(query)` to my Document model to be able to search documents using Sphinx and Riddle:

```
class Document
    ...
  @@riddle=Riddle::Client.new

  scope :search, ->(query){
    where(:document_id.in => sphinx_get_ids(query))
  }

  def self.sphinx_get_ids(query)
    @@riddle.query(query)[:matches].collect {|match| match[:attributes]["doc_id"]}
  end

end
```

Don't mind class variable.

I would like to set `offset` and `limit` parameters of riddle client before the query hits index(for performance reasons, obviously), but I cannot specify these options from scope block, because they are class level and, well, may not yet be initialized, like in this example with Kaminari:

`Document.search('graceful aubergine').page(5).per(10)`

This approach seems rather beautiful to me, but I still cannot find a way to implement it.

Is there a way to create a scope method that will be called on instance level right before query gets instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is not possible in current version of Mongoid and the one in development:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2652